# When asking what a certain building within sight is, would "あれ" or "あの" be used?

Tags: grammar

If I were to point to a building and ask what it was, would it be appropriate to say
"あれ は なん です か", "あの たてもの は なん です か", both, or something completely different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are perfectly correct and natural-sounding.

Another word we also often use in these situations is 「あそこ」, which means "that place".  You can say:

「あそこはなんですか。」

To speak more informally, we say:

「あそこはなに？」or even:

「あそこはなんなの？」